# How to Modify the existing dataframe passed to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I m trying to modify the same dataframe that I pass to a function but the changes are not visible

when I apply changes to the dataframe outside the function the expected results is achieved

```
test_df = test_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("\t") if x.dtype == "object" else x)
```

printing out unique values -

```
print ("{0}-->{1}".format(val,pd.unique(test_df[val])))
```

O/P-

```
htn-->['yes' 'no']   
dm-->['yes' 'no' '  yes']  
cad-->['no' 'yes']
appet-->['good' 'poor']  
pe-->['no' 'yes']  
ane-->['no' 'yes']  
classification-->['ckd' 'notckd']
```

However if I pass the Dataframe to a function and apply the above same functions the changes are not observed

```
def FillMissing(dataFrame):
    dataFrame = dataFrame.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("\t") if x.dtype == "object" else x)


FillMissing(test_df)
```

O/P-

```
htn-->['yes' 'no']  
dm-->['yes' 'no' ' yes' '\tno' '\tyes']  
cad-->['no' 'yes' '\tno']  
appet-->['good' 'poor']  
pe-->['no' 'yes']  
ane-->['no' 'yes']  
classification-->['ckd' 'ckd\t' 'notckd']
```

How can I modify the same existing dataframe without declaring it a global variable.

Also I have tried inplace flag with the lambda function , it does not work

Comment: Would you like to consider returning the dataframe from the function and assigning it back to the dataframe object in the caller? Like `test_df = FillMissing(test_df)`

Comment: The function returns individual list based on the dtypes of the dataframe , I would not like to return the dataframe and assign it back to the caller 
 
like -

    obj,int_,float_ = FillMissing(test_df)

Comment: You are modifying the dataframe, *and* returning other information?

Comment: @StephenRauch - I want to modify the dataframe and  return other information as well

Comment: You might want to return the dataframe and the other info as a tuple. Because what is happening is that the `dataFrame` variable in your method (the one you have reassigned) is different from the `test_df` variable after that assignment statement executes. In case you would like a detailed explanation I can post it as an answer

Comment: return a `(df, whatever)` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner what a coincidence I too commented the exact same solution at the same time :)

Comment: @raghav710 you might have been 2s earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are facing is a typical dilemma of beginner pythonistas. Look at this example

```
a = 10
b = a
b = 11
```

When `b` is assigned the value of `a`, `b` and `a` are in fact pointing to an object created to store the value `10` (*Everything is an object in Python*). But when `b` is assigned a new value `11`, `a` is not assigned the value since it is still pointing to the old value `10`. Only the pointer `b` has changed

So when you do

```
def FillMissing(dataFrame):
dataFrame = dataFrame.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("\t") if x.dtype == "object" else x)


FillMissing(test_df)
```

Thought `test_df` and `dataFrame` initially have the same value, `dataFrame` is later reassigned the result of the `dataFrame.apply()` operation but `test_df` returns the same. A solution to this is to return the new dataFrame from the method, either singly or as a tuple if required.

**A nice diagrammatic reference**

http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/

> ...But in Python variables work more like tags unlike the boxes you have seen before. When you do an assignment in Python, it tags the value with the variable name....Other languages have 'variables'. Python has 'names'

Comment: I tried returning the dataframe and assigning it back to the caller , however additional nan values are observed

`def FillMissing(dataFrame):
    dataFrame.replace("\?",np.nan,inplace=True,regex=True)
    dataFrame = dataFrame.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("\t") if x.dtype == "object" else x)`
......    
return (dataFrame,object_dtype,int_dtypes,float_dtype)

test_df,obj,int_,float_ = FillMissing(test_df)


`htn-->['yes' 'no' nan]  
dm-->['yes' 'no' ' yes' nan]  
cad-->['no' 'yes' nan]  
appet-->['good' 'poor' nan]  
pe-->['no' 'yes' nan]  
ane-->['no' 'yes' nan]`

Comment: @VaibhavSharma I believe this could be related to the processing you are doing. Can you try printing the value of the dataframe within the method and after it returns, printing `test_df` to verify if both are the same?

Comment: @VaibhavSharma were you able to verify that?

Comment: I tried verifying as per your suggestion

the statement (marked by >>>) is causing the issue , I tried printing out the id of the variables 

`test_df = test_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("\t") if x.dtype == "object" else x)
print(id(test_df))`

`def FillMissing(dataFrame):
    dataFrame.replace("\?",np.nan,inplace=True,regex=True)
 >>>   dataFrame = dataFrame.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("\t") if x.dtype == "object" else x)
    print(id(dataFrame))`

O/P-
ID(test_df) - 4506895696
ID(dataFrame) - 4506896424
rbc-->[nan 'normal' 'abnormal']

not sure y ths happening

Comment: @VaibhavSharma one more thing to verify. if you do this `apply` operation on `test_df` itself, do you still get the same issue?

Comment: the issue is only observed inside the function, executing it as a standalone statement does not have any issues.

I have recently posted a question regarding the same

[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364134/unable-to-understand-the-difference-between-two-statements)

Comment: @VaibhavSharma ok