# Unable to understand the difference between two statements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I recently tried to strip ("\t") values from a dataframe.

```
def FillMissing(dataFrame):
    dataFrame.replace("\?",np.nan,inplace=True,regex=True)
    dataFrame[:] = dataFrame.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("\t") \
                                if x.dtype == "object" else x)
    print(id(dataFrame))
    .......
(test_df,obj,int_,float_)= FillMissing(test_df)

print(id(test_df))
```

O/P-

```
ID(dataFrame) - 4647827832

htn-->['yes' 'no']  
dm-->['yes' 'no' ' yes']  
cad-->['no' 'yes']  
appet-->['good' 'poor']  
pe-->['no' 'yes']  
ane-->['no' 'yes']

ID(test_df) - 4647827832
```

And by slightly modifying the method , The O/P changes

```
def FillMissing(dataFrame):
    dataFrame.replace("\?",np.nan,inplace=True,regex=True)
    ***dataFrame = dataFrame.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("\t") \
                                   if x.dtype == "object" else x)***
    print(id(dataFrame))
    .......
(test_df,obj,int_,float_)= FillMissing(test_df)

print(id(test_df))
```

O/P -

```
ID(dataFrame) - 4647827832
    htn-->['yes' 'no' nan]  
    dm-->['yes' 'no' ' yes' nan]  
    cad-->['no' 'yes' nan]  
    appet-->['good' 'poor' nan]  
    pe-->['no' 'yes' nan]

ID(test_df) - 4517467528
```

I m unable to understand the difference , in the statements.

Also while executing the strip outside the function on the `test_df` it works completely fine.

Snapshot of Data used--

```
     id   age     bp     sg   al   su       rbc        pc         pcc  \
0      0  48.0   80.0  1.020  1.0  0.0    normal    normal  notpresent   
1      1   7.0   50.0  1.020  4.0  0.0    normal    normal  notpresent   
2      2  62.0   80.0  1.010  2.0  3.0    normal    normal  notpresent   
3      3  48.0   70.0  1.005  4.0  0.0    normal  abnormal     present   
4      4  51.0   80.0  1.010  2.0  0.0    normal    normal  notpresent   
5      5  60.0   90.0  1.015  3.0  0.0    normal    normal  notpresent   
6      6  68.0   70.0  1.010  0.0  0.0    normal    normal  notpresent   
7      7  24.0   80.0  1.015  2.0  4.0    normal  abnormal  notpresent   
8      8  52.0  100.0  1.015  3.0  0.0    normal  abnormal     present   
9      9  53.0   90.0  1.020  2.0  0.0  abnormal  abnormal     present   
10    10  50.0   60.0  1.010  2.0  4.0  abnormal  abnormal     present   
11    11  63.0   70.0  1.010  3.0  0.0  abnormal  abnormal     present   
12    12  68.0   70.0  1.015  3.0  1.0    normal    normal     present   
13    13  68.0   70.0  1.020  0.0  0.0    normal  abnormal  notpresent   
14    14  68.0   80.0  1.010  3.0  2.0    normal  abnormal     present   
15    15  40.0   80.0  1.015  3.0  0.0  abnormal    normal  notpresent   
16    16  47.0   70.0  1.015  2.0  0.0  abnormal    normal  notpresent   
17    17  47.0   80.0  1.020  0.0  0.0  abnormal    normal  notpresent   
18    18  60.0  100.0  1.025  0.0  3.0  abnormal    normal  notpresent   
19    19  62.0   60.0  1.015  1.0  0.0  abnormal  abnormal     present   
20    20  61.0   80.0  1.015  2.0  0.0  abnormal  abnormal  notpresent   
21    21  60.0   90.0  1.020  0.0  0.0    normal  abnormal  notpresent   
22    22  48.0   80.0  1.025  4.0  0.0    normal  abnormal  notpresent   
23    23  21.0   70.0  1.010  0.0  0.0    normal    normal  notpresent   
24    24  42.0  100.0  1.015  4.0  0.0    normal  abnormal  notpresent   
25    25  61.0   60.0  1.025  0.0  0.0    normal    normal  notpresent   
26    26  75.0   80.0  1.015  0.0  0.0    normal    normal  notpresent   
27    27  69.0   70.0  1.010  3.0  4.0    normal  abnormal  notpresent   
28    28  75.0   70.0  1.020  1.0  3.0  abnormal  abnormal  notpresent   
29    29  68.0   70.0  1.005  1.0  0.0  abnormal  abnormal     present
```

Comment: In brief, `dataFrame[:]=...` updates the contents of the dataframe passed as the parameter (`test_df`).  `dataFrame=...` overwrites the local value of the parameter but does not modify the object passed as the parameter.

Comment: @DYZ- Thank you for the explanation , however is there a reference or documentation regarding the same. I tried searching for one , but could not find it

Comment: I don't understand your *** operation. Also, can you post the data you use? You can use `to_dict` to get data that we can use immediately.

Comment: @Tai - [link] (https://www.kaggle.com/csyhuang/predicting-chronic-kidney-disease/notebook) [link] 

The dataset can be downloaded from here

Comment: @VaibhavSharma you should be preparing it for us... This is your question. Help us to help yourself.

Comment: @Tai - dataset posted